# Temporary web site allowance using squid

Tags: proxy, squid

Is it possible for customize squid to temporary allow blacklisted website via the error page?

Similar to Webwasher functionality below where it can detect blacklisted website, show an error page with a green button which the user can click to have 30 minutes allowance to visit that website.

Thanks.

[image]

```
translation:

Access to the desired site requires your confirmation. 

Your selected internet site "http://www.amazon.com/" belongs to the category (Online shopping at). 
If access is business-related or held outside of working hours, please confirm this by clicking on the "confirmation" 

If the page longer than 30 minutes is selected, this message appears again. 

Thank you for your understanding.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have a button that reports the error to IT.. if users are stupid enough to push it for pr0n they get nailed.. I suppose you could use the same variables to populate a local php/perl function that modifies the acl, reloads the config and waits for cron to switch it back..

```
<br />If this is an error, please click the button below.
<br /><br />
<form method="post" action="http://proxy/catch.php">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="%U" />
<input type="submit" value="Please click here to report this as an error" /></form>
<br />
```

in /etc/squid/errors/ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

use `deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED blacklistedacl`